# setq and csv-mode variables

Tags: csv

Why can't I directly set csv-mode variables like that:

```
(setq csv-separators '(";" "\t"))
(setq csv-field-quotes '("\"" "'"))
```

and I'm forced to set it like that:

```
(custom-set-variables '(csv-separators '(";" "\t")))
(custom-set-variables '(csv-field-quotes '("\"" "'")))
```

?

So, with this init file for csv-mode, my personnal settings are taken into account:

```
(require 'csv-mode)

(defun my/csv-mode-set-properties ()
  "Set properties for editing CSV files."
  (custom-set-variables '(csv-separators '(";" "\t")))
  (custom-set-variables '(csv-field-quotes '("\"" "'")))
  (custom-set-variables '(csv-align-padding 2))
  (custom-set-variables '(csv-header-lines 1)))

(add-hook 'csv-mode-hook 'my/csv-mode-set-properties)

(provide 'init-csv-mode)
```

but not with that:

```
(require 'csv-mode)

(defun my/csv-mode-set-properties ()
  "Set properties for editing CSV files."
  (setq csv-separators '(";" "\t"))
  (setq csv-field-quotes '("\"" "'"))
  (setq csv-align-padding 2)
  (setq csv-header-lines 1))

(add-hook 'csv-mode-hook 'my/csv-mode-set-properties)

(provide 'init-csv-mode)
```

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work when you use `setq` but does work when you use `custom-set-variables`.

Comment: The assignment itself. Variables values are not changed with `setq`, but they are with `custom-set-variables`.

Comment: `setq` has no problem setting the values on my machine.  Please provide a complete working example.

Comment: @Dan I changed my post : the last code section is the working example.

Comment: No need the use csv-hook here.

Comment: Start Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`) and try the `setq`s.  Query the variable value with `C-h v csv-separators`.  If everything works (and it should), recursively bisect your init file (commenting out successive halves) to find out what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the csv-hook:

```el
(setq csv-separators '(";" "\t"))
(setq csv-field-quotes '("\"" "'"))
(setq csv-align-padding 2)
(setq csv-header-lines 1)
(require 'csv-mode)
(provide 'init-csv-mode)
```

Works

Comment: Unfortunatly I already tried, and it doesn't work... But I don't understand why.

Comment: Do you take this version of csv mode ?: https://github.com/emacsmirror/csv-mode

Comment: No, the next one: 1.6

Comment: Can't reproduce with 1.6 too. The problem is somewhere else in your init.el

Comment: After searching a while I found a working solution (with both 1.5 and 1.6), but I do not understand why. I simply put `(require 'csv-mode)` at the end of your proposal, just before the `provide`. Do you have any idea about why does it work ?

Comment: No it should work in the both cases

Comment: Any reason you don't use the version in GNU ELPA?  AFAIK that's the only half-maintained version.  Feel free to submit bug reports for that version using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @djangoliv If you put the `require` at the end of your code I can accept it to close the question.